# Javascript code reloads each page one extra time on each request

Tags: javascript, facebook-javascript-sdk

About a month ago or something i encountered this behaviour on code that has been working this far.
Whenever someone log-in via facebook, each page will reload extra one time.

For example user loads up index.php page then after javascript code fires page reloads once more, then after that it won't. So basically when you click link or refresh current page it reloads 2 times in total (1 from natural load and another from FB javascript)

The javascript code that has been giving problem i belive is:

```
FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function() {
  window.location.reload();
});
```

Why this reloads on each page refresh? Before it worked perfectly only on user login 1 time.

I have regular additional code in html:

```
xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml" xmlns:og="http://opengraphprotocol.org/schema/"
```

And javascript include right under body:

```
<div id="fb-root"><script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script></div>
```

Comment: Show your source code. Before continuing, check whether `reload()` appears more than once in the code (eg. through multiple calls).

Comment: @Rob W - Well that's about it for javascript part 
`FB.init({
      appId   : facebookappid,
      session : facebooksession,
      status  : true,
      cookie  : true,
      xfbml   : true
    });

    // whenever the user logs in, we refresh the page
    FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function() {
      window.location.reload();
    });`

Other part is done in php where i have no redirect headers or any other kind of thing related to facebook.

Comment: Try **`location.href=location.href;`** or **`location.reload(true)`** (instead of `location.reload()`. Do either of them produce the desired results?

Comment: @Rob W - Nah sorry same outcome. I tried all other browsers besides firefox, thought there might be some issue with it, but all other 4 produced same outcome. Commenting out `window.location.reload();` bit removed this issue. Might there be some changes to Javascript SDK that causes this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed - by following this post [FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function(response) { }) issue](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/6733348/fb-event-subscribeauth-login-functionresponse-issue)

Reference to working example - http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.getLoginStatus/

Note: Make sure you include **oauth : true** in your FB.init settings.